# How to kick out "ad" popping up when browser opens?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to parse some company names from a webpage. The selector I've defined are flawless. However, as soon as the webpage opens up an annoying `ad` pops up hiding the data and for that I can't reach there. How can i kick it out and parse the data I would like to. I've tried with switching several `iframes` available in that webpage but none of them worked. The existing one which I used within my script throws an error showing `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element`.

This is what i tried so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.inc.com/inc5000/list/2017")
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_id("jw_player_iconic"))
for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#data-container .row"):
    company = item.find_elements_by_css_selector(".company a")[0].text
    print(company)
driver.quit()
```

The pop-up ad is something like below (the bright one):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to wait for ad to close it by clicking "SKIP" button:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.inc.com/inc5000/list/2017")
driver.maximize_window()

try:
    ad_iframe_close = wait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[.='SKIP']")))
    ad_iframe_close.click()
except TimeoutException:
    pass

for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#data-container .row"):
    company = item.find_elements_by_css_selector(".company a")[0].text
    print(company)
```

This should allow you to wait to close ad frame or do nothing in case it didn't appear whithin 3 seconds

Comment: Thanks a lot sir Andersson, for you effective answer. I never come across a single instance of your solution to be ineffective. It always does the magic. It's a long time since I've heard from you. However, where did you find the location of that `iframe`? I meant, you must have seen it that is because you've used that expression `//span[.='SKIP']`. I spoiled few hours to solve it but failed. Thanks again.

Comment: You can find ad `iframe` with XPath `//iframe[starts-with(@id, "google_ads_iframe")]`.  I simply found it with dev console - nothing special. Also note that "SKIP" button is out of `iframe` so you don't have to switch to frame